# How to generate static page in next dynamic page next.config.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created two dynamic page but error displayed:

> exporting a Next.js application via next export disables API routes.
> This command is meant for static-only hosts, and is not necessary to
> make your application static. Pages in your application without
> server-side data dependencies will be automatically statically
> exported by next build, including pages powered by getStaticProps.
> Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/api-routes-static-export

I followed `exportPathMap` method using `next.config.js` but could not solve. Could you please check my config code below solve this issue?

Page Root: `pages/category/[list]/[id].js` and `pages/store/[list]/[id].js`

`next.config.js`

```
module.exports = { 
  
  images: {
    domains: ["dl8mjowvdz1rh.cloudfront.net", "app.ae"],
  },
  eslint: {
    // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has ESLint errors.
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  exportPathMap: async function (
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' }, 
      '/category/:list/:id': { page: '/category/:list/:id', query: { title: 'Category Page' } }, 
      '/store/:list/:id': { page: '/store/:list/:id', query: { title: 'Store Page' } }, 
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: As the link in the error mentions: "An `exportPathMap` path was matched to an API route.". You can't use API routes and export your app as static HTML (`next export`) at the same time. Either remove the API routes and export it statically, OR use `next build && next start` and remove `exportPathMap`.

Comment: I also added exportPathMap `{'/custom-page': {page: '/', query: {data: 'hello'}}}`. And now I am trying to generate with `next export`, but my `custom-page.html` is not being generated :(